# Warning: Failed prop type the prop "onPress" is marked as required in "Button", but its value is "undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I defined the prop _navigateToRegister, but when I press on the button nothing happens.
And also I have this mistake warning: Warning: Failed prop type the prop "onPress" is marked as required in "Button", but its value is "undefined"
Where is the mistake?

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';
import {
StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './src/screens/Login';
import Secured from './src/screens/Secured';
import Register from './src/screens/Register';

const LifeStorm = createStackNavigator({
Login: { screen: Login },
Register: { screen: Register },
Secured: { screen: Secured },
});

export default class ReactNativeStormpath extends Component {

state = {
isLoggedIn: false
}

render() {

if (this.state.isLoggedIn)
  return <Secured
      onLogoutPress={() => this.setState({isLoggedIn: false})}
    />;
else
  return <Login
      onLoginPress={() => this.setState({isLoggedIn: true})}
    />;
}

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent("App", () => App);
```

login.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ScrollView, Text, TextInput, View, Button } from "react-native";

export default class Login extends Component {

navigateToRegister = () => {
this.props.navigation.navigate("Register");
};

render() {
return (
  <ScrollView style={{ padding: 20 }}>
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 27 }}>Login</Text>
    <TextInput placeholder="Username" />
    <TextInput placeholder="Password" />
    <View style={{ margin: 7 }} />
    <Button onPress={this.props.onLoginPress} title="Submit" />
    <Button onPress={this.props._navigateToRegister} title = "Register" />
  </ScrollView>
);
}
}

module.exports = Login;
```

register.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
ScrollView,
Text,
TextInput,
View,
Button
} from 'react-native';

export default class Register extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView style={{padding: 20}}>
            <Text
                style={{fontSize: 27}}>
                Register
            </Text>
            <TextInput placeholder='E-Mail' />
            <TextInput placeholder='Username' />
            <TextInput placeholder='Password' />
            <TextInput placeholder='Confirm Password' />
            <View style={{margin:7}} />
            <Button
                    onPress={() => navigate("Login")}
                    title="Submit"
                />
            </ScrollView>
        )
   }
   }
```

P.S I am new in React Native.

Comment: Login: You need just:  <Button onPress={this.navigateToRegister} title = "Register" /> . because you are acess the function from this class and not from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you're not actually sending the `_navigateToRegister` prop to the component.

Which means that event if you log `this.props._navigateToRegister` to the console the result should be `undefined`. And because you're sending undefined value to onPress you get that prop type error.

If you want to reference the `navigateToRegister` method of your Login component you can do it like this:

```
<Button onPress={this.navigateToRegister} title = "Register" />
```